# Is it more grammatical to say “I'm going out into the public” or “I'm going out in public”?

Tags: american-english

Which sentence is more grammatical:

“I’m going out into the public.”

“I’m going out in public.”

Couldn’t one argue that “I’m going out in public” is the same as saying “Throw it in the trash” (which is incorrect) because that’d grammatically convey you’re throwing it while already in the trash?

Comment: "Going out in public" is the standard expression. Can "throw it in the trash" really be incorrect when it is so idiomatic?

Comment: A sentence can follow the rules of grammar but still be nonsense or not idiomatic. No-one would say 'into the public' because 'the public' isn't a place that can be entered.